A telegram bot written with Python crashes if added to groups
I wrote a telegram bot with python with "telepot".
There are two lists of questions.
The questions from list A and list B are asked at the same time.
You can reply with text or photo. Selecting /next takes you to the next question.
In chats with the bot it works correctly but if you add it to a group it crashes and gives looping errors
QuestionA= ["Question A1", "Question A2", "Question A3"]
QuestionB= ["Question B1", "Question B2", "Question B3"]

#mex
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    if chat_type in ['private', 'group', 'channel']:  

        if content_type == 'text':
            if msg['text'] == '/start':
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Welcome click to /play.")
            elif msg['text'] == '/play':
                Question_A= random.choice(QuestionA)
                Question_B= random.choice(QuestionB)
                # Invia le domande al giocatore
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Question A: {}".format(QuestionA))
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Question B: {}".format(QuestionB))
            elif msg['text'] == '/next':
                Question_A= random.choice(QuestionA)
                Question_B= random.choice(QuestionB)
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Next Question A: {}".format(QuestionA))
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Next Question A B: {}".format(QuestionB))
            else:
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Next question /next.")


        elif content_type == 'photo':
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Next question /next.")

#start bot
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
print('ongoing...')
bot.message_loop(handle)

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)


In console I have looping errors similar to this:
KeyError: "No suggested keys ['message', 'edited_message', 'channel_post', edited_channel_post', 'callback_query', 'inline_query', chosen_inline_result', 'shipping_query', 'pre_checkout_query'] in {'update_id': 123456, 'my_chat_member': {'chat': {'id': 11111111, ...etc...

I expect it to work the same in both groups and chat with the bot
